# OpenDayLight SDN: Can't get openflow table info via OpenDayLight RESTCOF

Tags: opendaylight

I'm trying to connect several openflow OVS instances to OpenDayLight SDN.

My switches succesfully attached and I can get nodes info via RESTCONF like this /rests/data/opendaylight-inventory:nodes

But I can't get openflow table information via TABLE url. Official documentation says I can use restconf request like this: /rests/data/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/node=openflow:121062366427215/table=0

But I'm getting error

```
{
    "errors": {
        "error": [
            {
                "error-tag": "data-missing",
                "error-message": "Schema for '(urn:opendaylight:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)table' not found",
                "error-type": "protocol"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

opendaylight version 4.4.2

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://serverfault.com/q/1128659/493026 on server fault.

Answer (score 0):

Try this URL.

```
/rests/data/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/node=openflow:121062366427215/flow-node-inventory:table=0
```

Inside the `OpenDaylight` inventory, it is `flow-node-inventory:table` instead of `table`.

```json
{
    "opendaylight-inventory:node": [
        {
            "id": "openflow:1",
            ....
            "flow-node-inventory:table": [
                {
                    "id": 62,
                    "opendaylight-flow-table-statistics:flow-table-statistics": {
                        "packets-looked-up": "0",
                        "active-flows": 0,
                        "packets-matched": "0"
                    }
                },
                …
```